# Change in setup to stop handlebars jack knifing

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars, fatbike

I picked up a new fat bike recently took it on the first ride, just some light trails felt good however during corners the bars feel like the want to collapse in towards the way I'm turning. Not sure if what part of the setup is causing this, but hoping to tweak setup to minimize this. Here are some of the things that came to mind.

- Shorter Stem
- layback seatpost (thou I feel this may make things worse)
- Smaller tire up front (but that kinda goes again the laws of mtbing)

Anyone been able to rectify this problem? Cheers!

bike in question: https://www.za1e.com/index.php/product/northrock-xc00-fat-tire-mountain-bike/

Comment: Just so we can eliminate this, are the forks installed the correct way around?

Comment: They are indeed but your comment made me what to check

Comment: I've seen bikes in Walmart with forks installed backward

Comment: indeed this one came in a box so I assembled it :)

Comment: How soft are you running the front tire pressure? Does it feel like the tire is trying to roll off the rim?

Comment: pressures seem fine nothing too rolly I could add maybe a few more psi but to be honest it was pretty bumping but maybe I noticed more because of lack of dropper

Comment: I'd strongly suggest going for a second ride and see if its any better.  Even a couple rides before you start changing things.

Comment: Do you have another bike against which you (subconsciously maybe) compare the fat bike's handling? If so, their handling properties may vary a lot just because their geometry, especially fork [trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_geometry#Trail) parameters, are different. Find (if possible) geometry charts for both bikes and compare their trail values. Other things, such as head tube angle, handlebar width, presence/absence of front suspension will also affect steering properties.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you just have to get used to the different sensations on the new bike, including is steering geometry, determining how much the wheel has to be turned for a given turn radius.

A different bike from what I'm used to always feels weird at first, particularly when steering. Heck, changing, say, the saddle height by more than an inch on the same bike can feel weird.

Steering is inherently counter-intuitive. After all, to turn right, you briefly steer left (whether consciously or not)!

These fat tires are inflated to low tire pressures, and have a high side wall height. Of course, that is going to affect handling. Anything that affects handling will give you a feeling, to which you react, to which the bike, in turn, reacts, amplifying the surprise.

Steering probably **lags** a bit on these fat tires compared to narrower ones due to the flexibility they introduce between the road and the rim. Say we are initiating a right turn. The front wheel briefly steers left, inducing a fall to the right which produces the necessary right tilt. At that moment, the steering is supposed to recover to begin turning right. If that recovery lags a little bit due to a squiggly, thick tire, that induced fall will continue a moment longer, leading to a sharper turn than anticipated.

If you feel you're going too sharp into a corner (say, right turn), you might subconsciously straighten the wheel slightly (effectively, making a slight left turn relative to the ongoing right turn). But that will induce a counter-steer that takes the bike tighter into the right turn, which then amplifies the original sensation.